# Can not run jar file on xubuntu

Tags: files, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file that I created on windows. And I would like to test if the my demo app will run as well on ubuntu. I tried by issuing java -jar Rfidtest.jar in the termnal, but I have the following results.

```
odroid@odroid:~/Documents/RFID$ java -jar RfidTest.jar
eglGetDisplay returned EGL_NO_DISPLAYGraphics Device initialization failed for :  es2
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:300)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:243)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:754)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:98)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:754)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:190)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:304)
    ... 5 more
```

I'm new to linux/ubuntu, hope anyone can help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do people chop off the last piece of a stack-trace-like thing and expect that someone will provide an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s)

> You should have a look at [this related bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33697) (free registration required) for help on how to troubleshoot your issue.
>   In summary, the recommendations are:
>
> - run the application with the -Dprism.verbose=true flag
> - check the detailed log that is produced
> - it may point to a missing garphics library: GTK 2.18 is required to run JavaFX on linux

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry for getting back too late...I found out that the development board I'm using was not capable of running JavaFx.